# Restart memcached and a java server using script

Tags: command-line, scripts

As of now, I am using the following commands to start, kill, restart my application on ubuntu.

> ps -ef | grep memcached
>
> ps -ef | grep java
>
> kill -9 "pid of memcached and java"
>
> sudo nohup java -classpath mCruiseOnServer_lib/ -jar mCruiseOnServer.jar 10.116.106.126 10.116.106.126 10.116.106.126 2>&1 > mcruiseonL.log &
>
> /usr/bin/memcached -m 128 -vvv -p 11211 -U 11211 -u ubuntu -d > memcached.log 2>&1 &

Is there a easier way to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you installed memcached from the software center or the standard repositories (which is highly recommended!), you can restart it using:

```
service memcached restart
```

If your java server provides an upstart script, then you should be able to use a similar command for that.   If not, you could potentially write an upstart script for it to automate your commands.